# Negative vw value is not recognized in translateX(-100vw)

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, translate-animation

I am using css transitions and a little javascript to make elements slide into the page from the left or right.

It works perfectly fine from the right side (starting from `transform: translateX(100vw);`).
But from the left side (negative translate value: `transform: translateX(-100vw);`) it does not work at all. There is no error, but the element pops up at the end of the transition without any "animated" movement.

Using a `px` value instead of `vw` for the negative/ left side also works fine. I found several examples where people used negative vw values and did not seem to have problems with it...

I also tried `transform: translateX(calc(0px - 100vw));`. No luck...

(I am not using any libraries etc.)

```
<!-- HTML -->

<div class="container">
  <div class="slide-in l"></div>
  <div class="slide-in r"></div>
</div>
```

```
/* CSS */

.slide-in {
  transition: transform 0.8s ease;
}
.slide-in.l {
  transform: translateX(-100vw); /* this is the line does not work */
}
.slide-in.r {
  transform: translateX(100vw);
}
.slide-in.show {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```
/* JavaScript */

const slider = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-in');

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    slider.forEach(s => {
        s.classList.add('show');
    })
});
```

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Could you make your code into a working snippet. For example, you have not told us what the show class does, nor what the slides consist of.

Comment: Are you sure there's no other css at play here, all i did was add some colors to the div to make them visible, in chrome it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `translateX(-100vw);` should work fine.
When you run this snippet you should see both rectangles sliding into view,
the green one from the left and the right one from the right.

```js
const slider = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-in');

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  slider.forEach(s => {
    s.classList.add('show');
  })
});
```

```css
/* CSS */

.slide-in {
  transition: transform 0.8s ease;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.slide-in.l {
  transform: translateX(-100vw);
  /* this is the line does not work */
  background-color: green;
}

.slide-in.r {
  transform: translateX(100vw);
  background-color: blue;
}

.slide-in.show {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<div class="container">
  <div class="slide-in l">a</div>
  <div class="slide-in r">b</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the super fast answer. Sometimes tech is magic... I tried sooo many things yesterday and nothing worked. Today, without any change, it workes prefectly fine. I did not even close and reopen the project.